# In how many ways we can arrange 12 people in a row if 5 men are constrained to sit next to each other together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In how many ways we can arrange  $12$ people in a row if $5$ are men and they must sit next to each other?

**My approach**

I consider $5$ men as one entity and so now there are $8$ people to be seated in a row, which is done in 8! ways. The $5 $ men considered as one entity can themselves be seated in $5!$ ways. So the total number of ways are $8!5!$ (multiplication rule). What's wrong with the approach?

Comment: Who said your approach is wrong ?

Comment: Well it's obviously wrong because $12 - 5 \neq 8$...

Comment: I think it is nothing wrong.  Who told you it is wrong

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan There are seven women and a block of five men to permute, giving us eight objects to arrange.  We then arrange the men within the block as amrx did.

Comment: There are 8 7!5!. @Ashwin Swaminathan

Comment: which amounts to 8!5!

Comment: I know perfectly well how to solve the problem.. the solution as stated is *wrong* because it says that there are 8 people to be seated in a row, when there are only actually 7.

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan The fictitious "8th person" is the group of 5 men, which we can position as if it were a single unit.

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan, the grouped entity is the eighth figuratively

Comment: I am well aware of that, but the OP did not make this clear in his solution. Mathematics is not "figurative"

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan I don't think OP literally meant 8 actual people, but what was meant was that for all intents and purposes we can think of the 5 men as one person because they all sit together.  This is indicated pretty clearly when OP said "I consider 5 men as one entity"

Comment: Ashwin, he solved the question in the spirit of the problem.  That is it

Comment: He just used string or rope method which is required in this question.

Comment: Pardon my way, but I mentally imagined the people to be objects and condensed 5 objects into 1 special object. Thinking like this helps me solve counting problems otherwise I would be stuck.

Comment: Your answer is fine.  Another way you could do this is to first arrange the 7 other people, then choose the gap for the 5 men, and then arrange the 5 men in this gap, giving $7!\cdot8\cdot5!$ (which is the same as your answer).

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to me. If there were only the 5 men present, there would be $5!$ choices. If there were 6 people present, the sixth person could sit either on the left side or the right, so $2! \times 5!$. And so on for $n$ total people, with $(n-4)!\times 5! .$ When $n=12$, we have $8!\times 5!$ different ways, as you say.